# Difference between invariant and contractive sets

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes, invariant-theory

I came across this particular notion of contractive sets. I know what an invariant set is, but can anyone explain what a contractive set is and the difference between invariant and contractive sets?

Comment: For all I know, "contractive set" means something that can be continuously deformed into a point, or more formally a topological space whose identity map is homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: I have no idea, however, what an "invariant set" is.

Comment: Invariant sets can be simply stated  as, once I enter the set I never leave out of it, I know the same applies for contractive sets, but I am not sure how to differentiate them.

Comment: But maybe I'm mixing up contractive and contractible. And thinking of it, "contractive" is used with semigroups in analysis, where a contractive semigroup is one made of operators with norm at most 1.

Comment: what norm do you use there, is it a spectral norm?

Comment: It's the operator norm. If $T:E\to F$ is a linear operator between Banach spaces, then $\|T\|=\sup_{x\in E\smallsetminus\{0\}}\frac{\|Tx\|_F}{\|x\|_E}$. This makes the space of bounded linear operators (i.e. linear operators with finite norm) a Banach space, as soon as $F$ is Banach.

Comment: Then yeah its simply a $L_{p,q}$ induced norm in Banach space. I guess what you stated in the first comment gives the answer for this particular question.

Comment: Perhaps. But before I answer, since I know zero about polytopes, epsilon about polyhedra and only ever heard of invariant theory today, I'll wait for confirmation :).

Comment: sure even I will wait for the answer.....